# matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 20 is different from 10)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to make linear regression model. Please help

```
database = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
x = database.iloc[:,0].values
y = database.iloc[:,1].values
x_train = x_train.reshape(1,-1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(1,-1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(1,-1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(1,-1)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor= LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)

#predicting the test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(x_test)
```

The error is :

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 20 is different from 10)
```

Comment: You will get  `x_train not defined` error once you restart your notebook or restart your kernel as you are reshaping x_train without defining it first. The reason why you are not getting any right now because notebook saved `x_train` in it's environment. Please provide the code where you split X and y in train and test set

Comment: Is there a good reason to reshape the train and test set? You are basically creating train test sets of 1 row and x dimensions. You should probably try without reshaping the train and test sets

Answer (score 0):

I think that after reshape, your `x_train` (10 dimensions I supposed) has a different dimension than `x_test` (20 dimensions), therefore the `matmul` function get error. You should check that